# VHDL coding vs schematic editor

Tags: vhdl

Can anyone who is an expert in HDL (VHDL/Verilog) give insight on the following:

1. Coding your design directly in HDL? or..
2. using a schematic editor?

I know that for simple designs, either would be sufficient.

However, in what cases is one approach better the other? 
I've gotten opinion that for complex designs, a schematic editing workflow ends up being harder to maintain. Is this true in practice?

I've only experience in Xilinx ISE but im well aware of other tools out there

Comment: Just FYI, subjective questions are generally not recommended for SO (see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)).

Comment: I think this is on topic, it's pretty answerable in a concise manner and I think the pros and cons of each can be summarised without making it an opinion thing

Comment: Could you confirm the type of schematic editor your thinking about? logic gate placement or higherlevel (Simulink)

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed. It's fine. It's also an interesting observation that none of the people who closed this question actually have any HDL tag rep.

Comment: I dont think my question was subjective. It is asking what the best tool is for a specific workflow. In this case the workflow is complex schematic designs. By workflow, i mean implementing a CPU (non-super scalar)  schematic on FPGA.

Comment: Morgan, thats interesting, ive only used the xilinx ISE schematic editor which works with low-level components (logic gates, mux).  I just drag and drop components to model what i wrote in VHDL.

Comment: @Jun How do you quantify 'the best tool is for a specific workflow' if you can not quantify it, then is it not opinion based? People weight the pros and cons differently, Speed of development versus flexibility, ease of reuse etc. NB you did not get any downvotes so people generally think it is a good question, but I do think it is opinion based and so not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the lower-level HDL modules I code by hand because in most cases you need fine control over how everything behaves. A tool may allow you to drag and drop in what you need, but you're limited to what they have in the toolset. Coding by hand allows you to do anything you want to and also allows you to minimise resource usage and only use BRAMS/resources where necessary. I have found that the HDL generated by a schematic editor tends to use more of the FPGA resources than one coded by hand.

Another point is that often HDL builds are scripted and the GUI tools are not used for final builds. Since the schematic editor is gui based, it's more difficult to automate a schematic build.

Having said all that, schematic editing is great for putting together the top level of a design, that is, wiring all the existing HDL blocks together. Rather than describing the behaviour of the low-level stuff, this is just a nice way of visualising how everything fits. I have recently been coding my own custom HDL IP by hand and using those in the Vivado schematic editor. It has worked quite well, so it really depends on how the tools are being used.

Comment: I think the reference to schematic editor was for placement of logic gates, so there would be no need for HDL to be generated, you have your gate level netlist already, because of this there are no limitations on what you can do it is just a very manual process.

Comment: @Morgan, the OP would need to clarify. There are schematic editors available for various levels of abstraction, however the least common (as far as I know) is the rtl editor which is why I addressed the higher abstraction levels. Also, the use of the word "directly" in reference to HDL in the original question indicates that HDL coding is the lower level of abstraction between the two suggested by the OP.

Comment: When working in a mixed signal or analogue environment the schematic editors are for transistor level. They should have access to the same libraries that the digital synthesis tools do, therefore logic cell (flip-flop, AND, OR) level schematic editors are very common across the electronics industry. This is probably different from a digital only perspective.

Comment: @StaceyAnne Yes that makes sense to use the schematic editor only for visualization. However when you mentioned: "Another point is that often HDL builds are scripted and the GUI tools are not used for final builds" I dont know how the Xilinx editor works but doesnt it internally generate HDL code given the schematic input? If this is the case then I think scripted builds would not be an issue.

Comment: @JUN HDL is a description of behaviour you want to be created in logic gates. If you have the design in logic gates why would you want to convert to HDL to convert back to logic gates?

Comment: @Morgan yes agree,i might have given the wrong impression. I just assumed that if you have a schematic representing a high-level design, then doesnt it compile down to vhdl? Im not too familiar with how HDL and schematic compilers work in-depth.

Comment: @Morgan after a bit of googling, I think it is Simulink that clarifies my question of a schematic tool that compiles to VHDL/Verilog

Comment: @Jun ok, Simulink with the HDL Coder toolbox can be used to generate HDL. Staceys answer applies to this type of tool, it can be a real time saver but often limited to what you can do.